# Where do I find the complete data of a completed football match

Tags: data-request, sports, football

I am looking for a complete data of a match with the players.

Like who scored the goal and assisted it is available but what about

- how many shots a player attempted
- how many passes a player completed
- positions of a player
- how many tackles a player made
- how many goals a GK saved, etc

Comment: you might have a scroll through here and self-answer if you find anything useful: https://datahub.io/collections/football

Comment: @philshem didn't help budd, all the data are too old